# AppStore: App downloadable only for 3GS and above?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

My test unfortunately show that my app runs too slow on an iPhone 3G.
Therefore I decided to support only iPhone 3GS and above.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1397/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009877).  Namely the `armv7` or `opengles-2` should filter to 3GS and above.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look at limiting the iOS Version that is required. I believe that a 3G phone cannot upgrade to 4.3. So if you mark it as requiring 4.3 or above you'll limit the phones that can run it.